# webpack-cli Moved webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

I used `npx webpack-cli init` to create my config file. I then decided to moved the created config files into a `config/` folder. Now when I run `serve` it tells me the mode hasnt been set. I imagine I need to update some setting but havent been able to find the location.

Where can I update this?

Edit: Or should I just run this command in the desired directory?

Answer (score 0):

By default `webpack-cli` will try to find the webpack configuration file under you project root, since you've moved it to `config` folder, you would have to specify the path to it, e.g.:

```sh
npx webpack serve --config config/webpack.config.js
```